# How to Implement Event-triggered Callback in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, callback, locking

Assume in a system, users will register a callback function with system and that callback function will be called when an event is triggered but if the event is already triggered, the user will synchronously call the callback function.

For example, user i registers cb i at time Ti,
and the event gets triggered at time Te. Assume that T1 < T2 < T3 <...< Tm < Te < Tm+1 < ... < Tn. At time Te, cb1, cb2, ... , cbm will be called. 
cbm+1, ..., cbn will be called synchronously.

So we need to implement two APIs: `void register_cb(cb)` and `void trigger_event()`.

Following is a Python implementation.

```
is_triggered = 0
mutex = 1
def register_cb(cb):
    q=deque([])
    wait(mutex)
    if is_triggered == 0:
        q.append(cb)
        signal(mutex)
    else:
        signal(mutex)
        cb()

def trigger_event():
    is_triggered = 1
    wait(mutex)
    signal(mutex)
    while q:
        q.popleft()
        cb()
```

How do we translate the code into C++ with the same multithread handling?

Comment: I have no knowledge on Python. Does calling `signal(mutex)` lock or unlock the mutex? It appears like it unlocks the mutex, is that correct?

Comment: @Tas Not quite sure either. That's just some example code from online.